# html/scss - Slideout menu not affecting content block untill a certain point

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, responsive

**Note:** This problem is only for the desktop version (`min-width: 64em`)
**Codepen demo:** https://codepen.io/luffyy/pen/powoLeb

**The problem**
The menu on de side (purple) should not affect the position and/or width of the `main` block (red)  **if** there is space enough to slide-out the menu on `hover`. The `main` block (red) should have a `min-width` and after that be as width as the content (green) is up untill it is full width and touches the menu. At this point when you slide-out the menu, the `main` block (red) now should be affected and become less width.

**What i tried**
I tried playing around with making the navigation a `position: fixed` and this works when the `main` is at it's min-width, but when it's full width the slide-out effect goes over it.

How should i go about this? Is this possible? Is my html structure good this way if i want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want ?

made some changes on:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .navigation {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 6rem;
    transition: width 0.2s;
    position:absolute; //added
    height:100%; //added
    left:0; //added
    top:0; //added
    bottom:0; //added
  }
  .navigation:hover {
    width: 18rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .main__wrapper {
    flex: 0 0 44.5em;
    width: calc(100% - 6rem); //added
    margin-left:6rem; //added
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohsen, unfortunately with this i still get that at some window sizes the navigation falls over the content. This should never be able to happen, and it should push the content when it does.

Comment: some window sizes, you mean bigger or smaller, because it works the way you are asking **@media only screen and (min-width: 64em) {**.